# Como validar los eventos de mouse (Hover y Down)

Tags: c#

Quisiera realizar una accion dependiendo de lo que se realice con el mouse, ej: si el mouse esta sobre un boton, cambiar el color de un label (mouse hover), si presiono el boton, el label cambie a otro color (mouse down), pero si el mouse ya dejo de estar sobre el boton y/o pulsarlo, que el label cambie a otro color.

Alguien sabe como seria la validacion?

Comment: estas trabajando sobre winforms?

Comment: si señor Ramiro Barone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si estas usando windows forms solo es cuestión de que utilices eventos.
Este seria el evento hover

```
 private void NombreDeTuBoton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,0,0);
        }
```

el evento para click

```
private void NombreDeTuBoton_MouseClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
         label.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,0,0);
}
```

y con el evento Leave es cuando tu puntero salga de los limites de tu boton o label

```
   private void NombreDeTuBoton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
             label.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(23,1,1);
}
```